# Goormaghtigh equation

Tags: nt.number-theory

For fixed prime $p$ and $q$ is it true that the following equation has at most one pair $(m,n)$ of solution?
$$\frac{p^n-1}{p-1}=\frac{q^m-1}{q-1}$$ where $m,n>1$.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451767/111-11-base-p-111-11-base-q/451793

Answer (score 7):

Yes for fixed $p,q$ it is know there is at most one solution.  Even without the condition $p,q$ prime.

This was proved by He and Togbé, [On the number of solutions of Goormaghtigh equation for given x and y](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0019-3577%2808%2980015-8) (Indagationes Math, 2008)